# Registros duplicados en query usando SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero que mes muestre el campo `EstadoMateria` de la tabla `AlumnoMateria` sin registros duplicados y los que no están que no muestre nada, como está hecho en la foto de resultado esperado.

Esta es la consulta de resultado obtenido (la cual funciona bien)

```
select IdMateria,NombreMateria
from Materias m
where not exists (select null
                 from AlumnoMaterias am
                where am.idMateria = m.idMateria
                  and am.EstadoMateria in ('aprobado', 'regularizado'))
```

Esta consulta la hice yo intentando solucionar mi problema, no funciona porque trae registros duplicados e inexistentes.

```
select Materias.IdMateria,NombreMateria,AlumnoMaterias.EstadoMateria
      from Materias,AlumnoMaterias
      where Materias.IdMateria not in
        (SELECT IdMateria
        FROM AlumnoMaterias
        WHERE (EstadoMateria='Aprobado' or EstadoMateria='Regularizado'))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entiendo que un registro en la tabla `Materias` puede estar relacionada a mas de un registro en la tabla `AlumnoMaterias`, cada cual con tal vez diferentes valores para `EstadoMateria`. ¿Qué deseas hacer en ese caso? ¿Mostrar mas de un registro para esa materia para cada `EstadoMateria` diferente? ¿O siempre quieres mantenerlo a un solo registro por materia,en cual caso debes definir cómo obtener el valor para el campo `EstadoMateria`, ya que hay mas de un valor posible?

Comment: Quiero mantener un solo registro por materia. Cada registro de materia con su respectivo EstadoMateria y las materias que no existan en la tabla alumnosmaterias no tienen ningun EstadoMateria.

Comment: Hola @Arnaldo no me queda muy claro lo que deseas pero no importa, vayamos por partes, tengo una pregunta, ¿por qué en la subconsulta pones `select null from AlumnoMaterias ....`. Intento adecuar tu *query* para que en lugar de una subconsulta sea por medio de `JOIN`s pero antes de eso me gustaría que me dijeras el objetivo del `select null`

Comment: Entendido, un registro por materia, eso está claro. Lo que aún no entiendo es ¿qué resultado esperas si una materia está relacionada a más de un registro en la tabla `AlumnoMaterias` con diferentes valores para `EstadoMateria`. Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes la materia `Matemática` con `idMateria` 104. Ahora digamos que en la tabla `AlumnoMaterias` existan 2 registros con `idMateria` 104. Uno tiene `EstadoMateria` `'A'` y el otro `'B'`. ¿Cual valor para `EstadoMateria` debería usarse para la consulta?

Comment: @Flxtr: El `select null` viene de la respuesta que le dí a su pregunta anterior.  Cuando haces un `WHERE EXISTS` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, la claúsula ignora el valor que devuelve la subconsulta, solo le interesa la presencia o no de un registro.  Por lo que a mi me gusta hacer `select null` para dejar claro que el `select` en sí no tiene importancia.  Pero eso es solo mi estilo personal. Muchos prefieren usar `select 1`, aunque no afecta en nada el resultado.

Comment: @sstan comprendo, gracias por la aclaración. Respecto a tu pregunta ***qué resultado esperas si una materia está relacionada a más de un registro en la tabla AlumnoMaterias con diferentes valores para EstadoMateria*** entiendo que un alumno solo estará relacionado a una materia, y la materia solo tendrá un estado, es decir, se mantiene la relación 1:1 y con esto sería más sencillo poder determinar una solución. Esto es lo que me indica la lógica, sin embargo no es algo de lo que estoy seguro, todo depende de las necesidades del OP.

Comment: @Flxtr: Si la relación fuera 1:1, OP no tendría duplicados. Y aunque un alumno pueda estar relacionado a una sola materia, me imagino que lo opuesto no es cierto. O sea que, seguramente que, para una materia, pueden haber varios alumnos, y adicionalmente, me imagino que cada alumno puede tener un valor distinto para `EstadoMateria`, de lo contrario no tendría sentido que ese campo existiera en esa tabla.

Comment: @sstan@Flxtr La consulta con join no es para este caso, si o si es por subconsulta. porque filtro datos de una tabla con datos de otra tabla.  En la tabla materias son los 4 campos foreing key. cada alumno, con sus materias, y cada materia tiene su unico estado.

Comment: @Arnaldo: *cada materia tiene su unico estado*. Si este es el caso, ¿por qué está definido el campo `EstadoMateria` en la tabla `AlumnosMaterias`? Si de verdad fuera único por materia, ¿no se definiría en la tabla `Materias`? Algo no cuadra en la explicación. Te invito a repasar los otros comentarios que he hecho. Verás que la única explicación posible de los duplicados es porque un valor `idMateria` puede repetirse varias veces en la tabla `AlumnosMaterias`, lo que tiene como consecuencia adicional que cada materia no necesariamente tiene un único estado como lo supones.

Comment: @sstan lo entiendo, parece ser que tengo una solución, espero que le funcione al OP

Comment: @sstan me tome la molestia de crear unas pruebas en un editor de SQL en línea, aquí podrías realizar la prueba http://rextester.com/DLMXX7584

Comment: @Arnaldo: Para aclarar, ¿puedes incluir en la pregunta el resultado que obtienes con los duplicados?

Comment: @Flxtr tenias razon un left join pero le tenia que arreglar la subconsulta que excluye las materias aprobadas y desaprobadas para  solucionar mi problema. Valoro mucho el tiempo que se tomaron para constestarme. Estoy haciendo un proyecto en .net y esta consultaba me estaba matando ya que soy principiante en esto.

Answer (score 2):

En lo personal y por motivos de rendimiento prefiero construir consultas por medio de `JOIN`, para lo cual, siguiendo tu resultado esperado utilizaría el siguiente *query*:

```
SELECT M.IdMateria, M.NombreMateria, AM.EstadoMateria
FROM Materias M
    LEFT JOIN AlumnoMaterias AM 
        ON M.IdMateria = AM.IdMateria
```

## Actualización

Puedes revisar los resultados [aquí](http://rextester.com/DLMXX7584)

Comment: Funciona porque solo tienes un estudiante. Si lo pones un segundo, allí se ven los duplicados: http://rextester.com/JLWI20662. Y seguramente la tabla de verdad tiene varios estudiantes.

Comment: @sstan exacto, va a salir duplicado porque también se toma en cuenta el `NoAlumno`, entonces considero que también se tiene que agregar el `NoAlumno` para distinguir a qué materia hace referencia cada alumno

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto :

```
select distinct m.IdMateria,NombreMateria,am.EstadoMateria
from Materias m,AlumnoMaterias am
where not exists (select null
             from AlumnoMaterias am
             where am.idMateria = m.idMateria
             and am.EstadoMateria in ('aprobado', 'regularizado'));
```

prácticamente lo que cambió fue agregar la palabra distinct en la query lo cual evitará registros duplicados.

Comment: En efecto, esto va a reducir ciertos duplicados, pero no necesariamente va a devolver un registro por materia como OP quiere. El problema está con que `am.EstadoMateria` puede tener mas de un valor distinto por materia. Al menos, eso supongo. De lo contrario, no tendría sentido que el campo exista en esa tabla.

Comment: ya he probado con distinct, pero no funciona. gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

```
Esta era mi solucion. El left join y le agregue una subconsulta.
```

Me trae todas las materias de Materias pero me excluye las materias que estan en la tbl alumnomaterias con estado aprobado o regularizado y muestra el estado de las materias que estan inscripto o desaprobados, ya que las que estan aprobado o desaprobado en este caso no las queria ver. Gracias a todos me ayudaron un muucho.

```
SELECT M.IdMateria, M.NombreMateria, AM.EstadoMateria,NroAlumno
FROM Materias M
LEFT JOIN AlumnoMaterias AM 
    ON M.IdMateria = AM.IdMateria AND NroAlumno=2016009
    where  (M.IdMateria not in (SELECT IdMateria
                        FROM AlumnoMaterias
                        WHERE  EstadoMateria='Aprobado' or EstadoMateria='regularizado'))
```

Comment: Arnaldo, si esta es tu respuesta, deberías [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).